# Inapp promotion issues in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, in-app-promotions

Apple new Feature for inapp Promotion like

[For more description](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/promoting-in-app-purchases/)

i already Configure the iTunes  setup, but i am confuse how to use **SKProductPromotionConroller** in inapp product page.

```
let storePromotionController = SKProductStorePromotionController.default()
storePromotionController.update(storePromotionVisibility: .hide, forProduct: proSubscription,
completionHandler: { (error: Error?) in
    // Complete here
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, anything on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

In-App Promotion is Optional. 
Suggestion: to use, if you have an amazing new product in very popular game and your fans awaiting something new (new futures, new adventures e.t.c).

So, it must be really great for promotion, over-wise it will be ANTI promotion.

storePromotionController manages In-Apps (if many) on your product page right with app Icon.

Don't use it, if you are NOT big company like World Wide Game developer or your have really great amazing future to promote.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by ANTI promotion. Can using this hurt app promotion?